# how to find key from any array php

Tags: php, arrays, array-key

I have a string, I need to know at what index is that string exist in the array. My array is as follows:

```
array(3) 
{
    [0]=>object(stdClass)#47170 (3) 
    {
        ["countries"]=>string(2) "HK"
        ["last_seen_date"]=>string(10) "2016-09-17"
        ["ad_uid"]=>string(14) "157d5908a1ca83"
    }
    [1]=>object(stdClass)#47171 (3) 
    {
        ["countries"]=>string(2) "HK"
        ["last_seen_date"]=>string(10) "2016-09-27"
        ["ad_uid"]=>string(14) "157d7978513bc3"
    }
    [2]=>object(stdClass)#47230 (3) 
    {
        ["countries"]=>string(2) "HK"
        ["last_seen_date"]=>string(10) "2016-09-27"
        ["ad_uid"]=>string(14) "157ea7239824e9"
    }
}
```

The last seen date is:**2016-09-27**.
I would like to know at what index does **2016-09-27** exist in the array. So I know what is **ad_uid** related to that date. I have a method which does this.

```
 public function getAd_uid($last_seen_date,$values){      
 $key = array_keys($values,$last_seen_date);
 print_r($key);    
 }
```

The result gets an empty array. I have tried array_serach() has same empty results. Any other alternative solutions to achieve results?

Comment: You want to search an array key? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php Or you want to search for array value? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: You mean "what indexes", not a single index, right?

Comment: Yes, not a single index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all `$ad_uids` last_seen at particular date you can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) which will return you all elements you are looking for. If you need ad_uids only, you can apply [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to that array as following:

```
<?php
// $array is the array in question.

$filtered = array_filter($array, function($item) {
    return $item->last_seen_date == "2016-09-27";
});

$ad_uids = array_map(function($item){return $item->ad_uid;}, $filtered);
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/09a7a5ca4a3df09058c82b582b5c80e75e39cd88)

Answer (score 0):

As each each entry of your array is an object and you know the attributs' names of theses objects (I assume they never change), I would do it like this :

```php
/**
 * @param   string  $last_seen_date
 * @param   array   $values
 * @return  mixed   null|int
 */
function getAdUid($last_seen_date, array $values) {
    // Just in case no entry match
    $matching_index = null; 
    // Loop through each entry: $entry is an object
    foreach($values as $index => $entry) {
        if($entry->last_seen_date == $last_seen_date) {
            $matching_index = $index;
            break; // end loop: we found that we are looking for
        }
    }

    return $matching_index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to do that just loop your array

```
foreach($values as $key => $row) {
    // do something
}
```

then check if `$last_seen_date` is equal to the loop index last_seen_date `$row->last_seen_date`

```
if ($row->last_seen_date == $last_seen_date) {
   return $key;
}
```

if it is just return it

```
return $key;
```

so your php code would be like this

```
$arr = array(
    0 =>
        (object)array(
        "countries" => "HK",
        "last_seen_date" => "2016-09-17",
        "ad_uid"=> "157d5908a1ca83"
    ),
    1 =>
        (object)array(
        "countries" => "HK",
        "last_seen_date" => "2016-09-20",
        "ad_uid" => "157d7978513bc3"
    ),
    2 =>
        (object)array(
        "countries" => "HK",
        "last_seen_date" => "2016-09-26",
        "ad_uid" => "157ea7239824e9"
    )
);
function getAd_uid($last_seen_date, $values){
    foreach($values as $key => $row) {
        if ($row->last_seen_date == $last_seen_date) {
           return $key;
        }
    }
} 


echo '2016-09-17 is on index => '.getAd_uid('2016-09-17', $arr).'<br>';
echo '2016-09-20 is on index => '.getAd_uid('2016-09-20', $arr).'<br>';
echo '2016-09-26 is on index => '.getAd_uid('2016-09-26', $arr).'<br>';
```

**RESULT**

[image]

[**Working Demo**](https://www.tehplayground.com/LSn9jdi1muXLRu73)